# Production Log level :warn but I want more data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have my log level set to WARN in production (to cut the size of my log file), but when an error occurs, all I get is the stack trace ... no url, ip address, request parameters or anything like that.

Is there anyway to get this information even though my log level is set to WARN?

Comment: Why not simply changing it to "error" ? or "info" ? if you are worried about your filesize you should probably just practice some log rotation mechanism.

Comment: :info logs all the successful queries ... google, yahoo and bing are *constantly* spidering the site, so that when an error occurs it can be tough to find the problem and the stack trace in the log. :error is the next level after :warn, and that would log even fewer problems than it is currently ... from what I understand

Answer (score 0):

You may try to add a rescue handler to your controller or controllers and log interesting things there:

```
def rescue_action_in_public(exception)
  logger.error "Parameters: #{params.inspect}"
  super
end
```

But I suggest that setting the logger level to INFO would be a better thing.